# How to define empty array in UML class diagram?

Tags: uml, class-diagram, magic-draw

While learning how to create UML class diagram using MagicDraw, I want to represent array variable `Integer [] ids;`

I tried `~ids : Integer []`, but got an error. I suppose I have to specify the size of the array in the brackets. How to specify an empty array properly?

Comment: What do you mean by empty array. An array that can be empty or one that is always empty?

Comment: @Ister I declared an array like this `Integer [] ids; ` .  This array is initialized later with random size so I don't know what to write in the brackets in the class diagram. Answering to your question, the one that can be empty, I guess .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would probably do it like this:

[image]

Just with an empty array as default. I have to confess that I don't know how to technically achieve that with MagicDraw.